# How to calculate Martingale Residuals by hand?

Tags: self-study, residuals

I know we require the breslow estimator for this. But is there a concrete formula to find this by hand? Supposing we're given a data set of 6 individuals (nothing too big) and we know when each individual has their outcome. What would the formula to calculate this by hand be?